# How can I rename or edit a User in Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

Is it possible to rename or edit a User in Databricks (in Azure) once they have been created?

When I was first given access to Databricks, the admin spelled my last name incorrectly. From that point on, every time I create something it pulls in that incorrect last name. This even happens after changing Azure subscriptions and creating a brand new workspace myself and therefore the Admin. However, I cannot find any option to edit a user, including my own user info.

[image]

For example, when I go to create a new cluster, it pulls in the misspelled last name:

[image]

Comment: most probably your account has identity federation enabled, then your user name should be edited there